# Trouble getting my script to loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fading div that shows reviews and loops them, making them pop up and fade in/out into the next one. But somehow, only the right div will loop while the left one will only play all of it's reviews once before just going into `display: none;` and not looping the script.

Anyone know why it doesn't do what it should do?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('img.bgfade').hide();
  var dg_H = $(window).height();
  var dg_W = $(window).width();
  $('#wrap').css({
    'height': dg_H,
    'width': dg_W
  });

  function anim() {
    $("#wrap img.bgfade").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(5000);
    $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(5000);
    setTimeout(anim, 5000);
  }
  anim();
})
$(window).resize(function() {
  window.location.href = window.location.href
})


$(document).ready(function() {
  var allBoxes = $("div.boxes-left").children("div");
  transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
  function next() {
    var nextTo;
    if (to.is(":last-child")) {
      nextTo = to.closest(".boxes-left").children("div").first();
    } else {
      nextTo = to.next();
    }
    to.fadeIn(3000, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        transitionBox(to, nextTo);
      }, 6000);
    });
  }

  if (from) {
    from.fadeOut(3000, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var allBoxes = $("div.boxes-right").children("div");
  transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
  function next() {
    var nextTo;
    if (to.is(":last-child")) {
      nextTo = to.closest(".boxes-right").children("div").first();
    } else {
      nextTo = to.next();
    }
    to.fadeIn(2000, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        transitionBox(to, nextTo);
      }, 3000);
    });
  }

  if (from) {
    from.fadeOut(3000, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

```css
#leftmenu {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#rightmenu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  margin: 400px auto 0;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="boxes-left">

      <div class="box1">
        <h3>Review #1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id sem libero. Duis sit amet pretium sapien.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box2">
        <h3>Review #2</h3>
        <p>Ayy lmao ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesque leo, eu pulvinar velit.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box3">
        <h3>Review #3</h3>
        <p>Aeouoi sagittis justo sit amet odio commodo, in malesuada nulla elementum. Integer pretium, sem nec vehicula dapibus.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="right">
    <div class="boxes-right">

      <div class="box1">
        <h3>Review #1</h3>
        <p>Nam ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesqu Duis sit amet pretium sapien.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box2">
        <h3>Review #2</h3>
        <p>Nam ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesque leo, eu pulvinar velit.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box3">
        <h3>Review #3</h3>
        <p>Pellentesque sagittis justo sit amet odio commodo, in malesuada nulla elementum. Integer pretium, sem nec vehicula dapibus.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

**Bonus question:** I want to put a setTimeout function in front of the whole thing but when I try it gives me an error. How would I go about making that work?

Comment: 1. don't ask 2 questions in 1 question, 2. if you have an error, please be so kind and give the error message (not to talk about the code that causes it), 'cause most of us here can't read minds

Comment: Tip: Rather than pass `null`, pass `$()` which is an empty jQuery collection.

Comment: Q: `window.location.href = window.location.href`? Do you mean to just `window.reload()`? Q2: Why refresh on resize? Make the code responsive instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2v7y9nhw/3/embedded/result/

Comment: There is no error message. I just doesn't loop the script. it plays all the reviews once and then just stops. I'm sorry if the code doesn't make too much sense. I didn't write it myself I'm  just trying to make sense of it. I'm still learning jquery. If you want to see what I'm talking about go to www.breunesse.info . user: admin pass: concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have defined the function `transitionBox` twice, once with left logic and then with right logic, so the second one is overriding the first one so when the last element is reached only right panels logic is executed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allBoxes = $("div.boxes-left").children("div");
  transitionBox1(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox1(from, to) {
  function next() {
    var nextTo;
    if (to.is(":last-child")) {
      nextTo = to.closest(".boxes-left").children("div").first();
    } else {
      nextTo = to.next();
    }
    to.fadeIn(3000, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        transitionBox1(to, nextTo);
      }, 6000);
    });
  }

  if (from) {
    from.fadeOut(3000, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var allBoxes = $("div.boxes-right").children("div");
  transitionBox2(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox2(from, to) {
  function next() {
    var nextTo;
    if (to.is(":last-child")) {
      nextTo = to.closest(".boxes-right").children("div").first();
    } else {
      nextTo = to.next();
    }
    to.fadeIn(2000, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        transitionBox2(to, nextTo);
      }, 3000);
    });
  }

  if (from) {
    from.fadeOut(3000, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

```css
#right {
  background-color: red;
}
#left {
  background-color: green;
}
#leftmenu {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#rightmenu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 70px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  margin: 400px auto 0;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="boxes-left">

      <div class="box1">
        <h3>Review #1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce id sem libero. Duis sit amet pretium sapien.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box2">
        <h3>Review #2</h3>
        <p>Ayy lmao ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesque leo, eu pulvinar velit.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box3">
        <h3>Review #3</h3>
        <p>Aeouoi sagittis justo sit amet odio commodo, in malesuada nulla elementum. Integer pretium, sem nec vehicula dapibus.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="right">
    <div class="boxes-right">

      <div class="box1">
        <h3>Review #1</h3>
        <p>Nam ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesqu Duis sit amet pretium sapien.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box2">
        <h3>Review #2</h3>
        <p>Nam ut nunc id turpis consequat vestibulum eget sit amet arcu. Nullam nec pellentesque leo, eu pulvinar velit.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box3">
        <h3>Review #3</h3>
        <p>Pellentesque sagittis justo sit amet odio commodo, in malesuada nulla elementum. Integer pretium, sem nec vehicula dapibus.</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2v7y9nhw/embedded/result/)

Comment: Awesome. You're a hero.